# Use botocore to list content of S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I need to list files of the S3 bucket. But in the project we don't want to create new dependencies and use boto3. Instead, we want to use botocore.

Do you know how to implement this using Python if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All AWS services expose **REST API**:

- [Amazon S3 REST API Introduction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)

Thus you can use that, but using this  means that you have to basically re-implement `boto3` anyway, including authentication, all security protocols, exceptions. Off course you have to maintain it if S3 API changes.